# Python How to read text file with certain format and convert it into dataframe

Tags: python, text, import

This file saves the paper information and the citation network. The format is as follows:

```
#index ---- index id of this paper
#* ---- paper title
#@ ---- authors (separated by semicolons)
#t ---- year
#c ---- publication venue
#% ---- the id of references of this paper (there are multiple lines, with each indicating a reference)
```

The following is an example:

```
#index 1
#* Book Review: Discover Linux
#@ Marjorie Richardson
#t 1998
#c Linux Journal

#index 2
#* MOSFET table look-up models for circuit simulation
#@ 
#t 1984
#c Integration, the VLSI Journal

#index 1083734
#* ArnetMiner: extraction and mining of academic social networks
#@ Jie Tang;Jing Zhang;Limin Yao;Juanzi Li;Li Zhang;Zhong Su
#t 2008
#c Proceedings of the 14th ACM SIGKDD international conference on Knowledge discovery and data 
mining
#% 197394
#% 220708
#% 280819
#% 387427
#% 464434
#% 643007
```

I am trying to convert this file into a data frame that I can work with.
I tried to use a for loop to loop through the lines and created many if statements to determine the type of information and append it to the designated list(paper_title, authors, etc), and finally, combine them into a single data frame. However, I noticed that there could be multiple reference IDs like the example showed, so the row of the reference id won't match the rest. Please help!

Comment: you will have to keep all `IDs` as list in one cell. OR you will have to keep `IDs` in separated table with columns `index, id` - like in `database` with two tables. But as for me this document doesn't fit to `DataFrame` and it should be converted to `database` with two tables. And if you want to split authors then it should have also table `index, author`

Comment: @furas Do you mean I should insert this into a database like MySQL? I'm very new to programming, how exactly should I write the LOAD DATA INFILE with the format given?

Comment: I think that data will be more usefull in database - but database doesn't have method to load it. In both situations (dataframe or database) you have to write the same code to parse it and almost the same code to put in rows.

Comment: BTW: there is empty line between citations - so I would use it to split text - `citations = text.split('\n\n')` - and later you can create function which parse one citation and run this funciton in `for`-loop - `for cit in citations: results.append(parse(cit)):`. And this way code should be simpler and smaller.

Comment: if citation has one line with title, one line with authors, one line with year, one line with publication, and rest with IDs then you could use `lines = citation.split('\n')` and `title = lines[1]`, `authors = lines[2]`, ... , `pub = lines[4]`, `ids = lines[5:]`

Answer (score 1):

If every element (index, title, authors, year, pub) uses only one line then you can simply convert it like this

```
text = '''#index 1
#* Book Review: Discover Linux
#@ Marjorie Richardson
#t 1998
#c Linux Journal

#index 2
#* MOSFET table look-up models for circuit simulation
#@ 
#t 1984
#c Integration, the VLSI Journal

#index 1083734
#* ArnetMiner: extraction and mining of academic social networks
#@ Jie Tang;Jing Zhang;Limin Yao;Juanzi Li;Li Zhang;Zhong Su
#t 2008
#c Proceedings of the 14th ACM SIGKDD international conference on Knowledge discovery and data mining
#% 197394
#% 220708
#% 280819
#% 387427
#% 464434
#% 643007
'''

import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---

def parse(cit):
    lines = cit.strip().split('\n')
    index = lines[0].replace('#index ', '')
    title = lines[1].replace('#* ', '')
    authors = lines[2].replace('#@ ', '')
    if authors:
       authors = authors.split(';')
    else:
       authors = []
    year = lines[3].replace('#t ', '')
    pub = lines[4].replace('#c ', '')
    ids = lines[5:]
    ids = [x.replace('#% ', '')  for x in ids]
    
    print('found index:', index)
    print('found title:', title)
    print('found authors:', authors)
    print('found year:', year)
    print('found pub:', pub)
    print('found IDs:', ids)
    print('---')

    return [index, title, authors, year, pub, ids]

# --- main ---
    
citations = text.split('\n\n')

rows = []

for cit in citations:
    rows.append(parse(cit))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['index', 'title', 'authors', 'year', 'pub', 'ids'])    
pd.options.display.max_columns = 100
print(df)
```

Result:

```
found index: 1
found title: Book Review: Discover Linux
found authors: ['Marjorie Richardson']
found year: 1998
found pub: Linux Journal
found IDs: []
---
found index: 2
found title: MOSFET table look-up models for circuit simulation
found authors: []
found year: 1984
found pub: Integration, the VLSI Journal
found IDs: []
---
found index: 1083734
found title: ArnetMiner: extraction and mining of academic social networks
found authors: ['Jie Tang', 'Jing Zhang', 'Limin Yao', 'Juanzi Li', 'Li Zhang', 'Zhong Su']
found year: 2008
found pub: Proceedings of the 14th ACM SIGKDD international conference on Knowledge discovery and data mining
found IDs: ['197394', '220708', '280819', '387427', '464434', '643007']
---
     index                                              title  \
0        1                        Book Review: Discover Linux   
1        2  MOSFET table look-up models for circuit simula...   
2  1083734  ArnetMiner: extraction and mining of academic ...   

                                             authors  year  \
0                              [Marjorie Richardson]  1998   
1                                                 []  1984   
2  [Jie Tang, Jing Zhang, Limin Yao, Juanzi Li, L...  2008   

                                                 pub  \
0                                      Linux Journal   
1                      Integration, the VLSI Journal   
2  Proceedings of the 14th ACM SIGKDD internation...   

                                                ids  
0                                                []  
1                                                []  
2  [197394, 220708, 280819, 387427, 464434, 643007]
```

There is empty line between citations so I split text on this line and later I run `for`-loop to convert every citation separatelly in function `parse()`. I assumed than every element uses only one line so it doesn't need `if/else` to check lines.

Because citation may have different number of IDs so it have to be as list in one column/cell. It can be more useful then putting everu ID in new column.

**EDIT:** now I split also authors to keep them as a list.

---

Eventually you could duplicate citation in new rows with single ID. In some situations it can be useful but in other situations it can makes problem.

Or you could keep IDs in separated table with columns `index, id` - like in database - but againg: in some situations it can be useful but in other situations it can makes problem.

I would keep it in database because it seems better tool for this type of data, and it has tools to work with many tables (relations).
It could have even separated table for authors - with columns `index, author`.

But at this moment I skip this part.

Comment: is there a way where I can use a regular expression to compile the file? Say If I want to capture the author, I can re.compile(re) anything that start with #@ and end with \n but not include #@

Comment: `re.compile('#@ (.*)')`